# Можно ли в стиле сделать Binding к свойству из ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Можно ли в стиле сделать Binding к свойству из ViewModel? Если да, то как?

Comment: Решите один вопрос сначала. Ведь если решили бы, то этого не было. Ну и игнорировать комментарии плохо!

Comment: Можно `<Setter Property="СвойствоКонтрола" Value="{Binding СвойствоВьюМодели}"/>`, странный вопрос. Куча документации и примеров в сети.